# Efficient arithmetic operator overloading in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

I have a POD struct that has a number of members, and I would like to know the most efficient way in C++11 to implement its arithmetic operators.

This struct is meant to be used in place of primitives in a mathematical context; for example:

```c
template<typename Double>
Double calcSomething(const Double& d0, const Double& d1, const Double& d2)
{
    return d0*d1 + 3*d2 - 6;
}
```

Where `Double` is either just a normal `double`, or is a POD struct with all the relevant overloaded operators:

```c
struct MyDouble
{
    MyDouble(double a, double b) : _a(a), _b(b) {}
    double _a;
    double _b;
};
MyDouble operator+(const MyDouble& d0, const MyDouble& d1) 
{
    return MyDouble(d0._a + d1._a, d0._b + d1._b);
}
```

Is there a really nice, efficient way to implement this in C++11 using move constructors and rvalue references? Keep in mind that `MyDouble` could be a large POD struct (i.e. not just two doubles).

I would like to keep the discussion about structs that do not have pointers to heap-allocated memory.

Comment: Move constructors aren't really going to do anything for you if all the memory is contained within the struct itself, but you still have return-value-optimization which likely makes the implied copies unnecessary.

Comment: Is the return value optimisation something that I should control (i.e. I need to write some code), or is it in the realms of compiler optimisation?

Comment: It is a compiler optimization.

Comment: And is that an optimisation available to c++03 as well as c++11?

Comment: Yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: What exactly is inefficient about doing it the simple and obvious way? Do you have profiling data that shows it's inefficient?

Comment: @Nicol The real issue is me not fully understanding move semantics. I'm just trying to probe to see where it can be put to good use.

Comment: @user1487088: Why not just ask about how move semantics work? Or even better, look up already existing questions about how move semantics work.

Answer (score 0):

If a struct doesn't *own* any other objects or resources, then move semantics and copy semantics are identical. Even a move constructor or move assignment operator needs to copy all data members to the target object. It just doesn't have to perform a *deep* copy, i.e. owned sub-objects are simply transferred to the target object, instead of being copied.

If your struct is truly huge, you can create a holder type which contains a pointer to a heap-allocated instance (using scoped_ptr, preferably). You can then support move on that holder type - actually, if you manage the actual instance with scoped_ptr, you'll get move support automatically, I think.